# "be already dishing" - what does it mean?

Tags: idioms

I am reading a book about [Elon Musk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/006230125X) and when the writer came to interview him.

**He was already dishing**

What does it mean?

For more context

*Our conversation began with a discussion of public-relations people. Musk burns through PR staffers notoriously fast, and Tesla was in the process of hunting for a new communications chief. “Who is the best PR person in the world?” he asked in a very Muskian fashion. Then we talked about mutual acquaintances, Howard Hughes, and the Tesla factory. When the waiter stopped by to take our order, Musk asked for suggestions that would work with his low-carb diet. He settled on chunks of fried lobster soaked in black squid ink. The negotiation hadn’t begun, and **Musk was already dishing.***

Comment: Putting a meal on one or more plates, having finished cooking it? We need much more context.

Comment: can you give more context?  Urbandict suggests "ranting" as a slang meaning of "dish"  https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dishing But urbandict is famously unreliable and I'm not clear from the context if this even makes sense. (seems to be a slang form of "discussing")

Comment: We do not have the book, but [this web page](http://decriresonjob.free.fr/blog/Lire-en-anglais/Elon-Musk.html) (on a French translation site) mentions 'chunks of fried lobster' in 'Chapter : Elon's world - Page 1 to 3' shortly before the dishing' phrase, which it balks at, which fits with the meal idea. Chefs talk about 'dishing' or 'plating'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dishing" literally means serving food, but is commonly used to mean speaking information. For example, "dishing the dirt" means gossiping (with "dirt" meaning potentially harmful details).

Although food is mentioned in this paragraph, the "dishing" is mentioned as being premature to the negotiations. It seems pretty clear to me it means that Musk was giving out details about the negotiations before they had officially begun.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Clearly